# Integration method unknown

Tags: integration

$$
\int \frac{4}{(x+y)^{2}} \,\mathrm{d}y = \frac{-4}{x+y}
$$
How do you get to that answer? I've been looking over my formulas, tried to compute the power and integrate after but no success.

Comment: $\int \frac{1}{y^{2}} dy=-\frac{1}{y}$ and assume x is a constant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $$
> \int \frac{4}{(x+y)^{2}} \,\mathrm{d}y = \frac{-4}{x+y}
> $$

Factor out constant:
$$
4\int \frac{1}{(x+y)^{2}}dx \
$$

For integrand $\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}$ substitute $u=x+y$ and $du=dy$:
$$
4\int \frac{1}{u^{2}}du \
$$

The integral of $\frac{1}{u^2}$ is $=-\frac{1}{u}$

$$
=-\frac{4}{u}+C
$$

Substitute back for $u=x+y$

$$
\color{blue}{=-\frac{4}{x+y}+C}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Make the substitution $u=x+y$. Since you are integrating with respect to $y$, $du=dy$ therefore you have

$$\int \frac{4}{(y+x)^2}dy= \int \frac{4}{u^2}du=4\int \frac{du}{u^2}=\frac{-4}{u}=\frac{-4}{x+y}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$\int {(f(y))^n f'(y)dy}=\frac{1}{n+1}f(y)^{n+1}$$

In your case, $f(y)=(x+y)^{-2}$. Can you take it from here?